# Propensity score matching for differently sized control and treatment groups

Tags: propensity-scores, control-group

I would like to use propensity score matching to construct a post hoc control group to accompany a pre-determined treatment group.

Some literature I am seeing says that I should pairwise match sample points from the treatment group to the control group. However I think this runs into two problems:

1. You could have (perhaps should have) fewer people with a high propensity score of your potential control group. So you couldn't pairwise match these people.
2. If my pool of potential control subjects is much bigger than my pool of treatment subjects, then I would like to leverage this fact to help with finding statistically significant differences. I could use twice the number and have two controls paired with each treatment person, but maybe I need 1.5 times as many people in my control.

**Isn't there a way to do this with weighting that would overcome both of these issues?**

Apologies, as I am sure that this is a fundamental issue but I am just confused by the pairwise issue and am wondering if there is some "robustness" point about score matching and control group generation that I am missing.

Edit: I am also not married to PSM as my control group generation method. If you think that other methods work better, or might work better for me, then I am all ears.

Comment: Genetic Matching (method = "genetic") in [matchit package](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/matching-methods.html#optimal-full-matching-method-full) seems to do what's you want

Comment: It’s good to not be married to this approach.  It has serious problems especially with power.  See https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is or how to answer it. Are you fundamentally asking whether to use weighting vs matching to create a control group balanced to your treated group? Or are you asking about how to adjust your matching specification to accommodate features of your data? Or are you asking about whether the problems you identified with propensity score matching are legitimate concerns? Your bold question differs from your title and several of your statements seem unrelated to each other or to your bold question. Please clarify and I'll do my best to answer.

Comment: I just need a way of matching to generate a control group for my pre-determined treatment group. But if my treatment group has 500 participants, say. And my control group could potentially have 3000, then 1 to 1 matching isn't optimal. It just seems to me that there must be a better way.